# OMP : Is REDUCTION mandatory for an array when in a DO loop there is no concurrency between cells?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I wrote the following program that works as expected.

```
program main

    use omp_lib
    implicit none

    integer :: i,j
    integer, dimension(1:9) :: myArray

    myArray=0
    
    do j=0,3
        !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)
        do i=1,9
            myArray(i) = myArray(i) + i*(10**j)
        end do
        !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    enddo
    
    print *, myArray
    
end program main
```

As only one thread writes to the i th cell of myArray, `REDUCTION` on myArray has not been used. But, I wonder if `REDUCTION (+ : myArray)` must be added in the `OMP DO` or if it is unuseful ? In others terms, what is important : the array or the cell of the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is important : the array or the cell of the array ?

**Cells**. `!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)` is fine as long as the loop is embarrassingly parallel. When Threads operate on the same location in memory, this cause a race condition. When a reduction is performed cell-wise, then `REDUCTION (+ : myArray)` can be added. That being said, once should note that the full array will likely be replicated in each threads temporary before doing the final reduction of the whole array. Since your loop is embarrassingly parallel, `REDUCTION (+ : myArray)` is not needed here.

Besides, note that **the number of iterations is too small for multiple threads to make the code faster**. In fact, it will be **slower** because of the time spent to create/join threads, the time to distribute the work amongst threads and also because of an effect called false-sharing (which will nearly serialize the execution of the loop here).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree this your note (_number of iterations is too small_). This is only a short example to sum up my problem.